# Powershell - want to ignore some object for "foreach-object" result depend en DFS Folders

Tags: powershell, directory

I checked everywhere, but I was not able to find the right answer.
I've a little script to list all folders in a volume and find the DFS folder depending of the folder to put inside zabbix.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
Param(
    [parameter(position=0,
        Mandatory=$true,
        HelpMessage="drive to check")]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$volume,
    [parameter(position=1,
 #       Mandatory=$true,
        HelpMessage="folders to check")]
        [string]$folders,
    [parameter(position=2,
        Mandatory=$true,
        HelpMessage="DFS path")]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$DFS,
    [parameter(position=3,
#        Mandatory=$true,
        HelpMessage="bypass folder")]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$bypassfolder,
    $DFSpath = "\\domain.lan\" + $DFS + "\",
    $search= $volume + ":\" + $folder + "*"
   )

Get-ChildItem $search -Directory -Name |
    ForEach-Object {
        $foldername = $_ -replace('\\','/')
        if (-Not ( $bypassfolder.Contains($foldername) )) { 
--> **wrong**  if (-Not (Get-DfsnFolder -Path "$DFSpath$folder*").Equals(!$Null)){
            $dfsname=Get-DfsnFolder -Path "$DFScomplet$nomdossier*"
            $dfsname=$dfsname.Path
            $dfsname=$dfsname.Split('\')
            $dfsname=$dfsname[4]
            $enr=$enr+"`{`"`{`#$search`}`":`"$foldername`",`"`{`#$DFS`}`":`"$dfsname`"`},"}}}
$enr=$enr.Substring(0,$enr.Length-1)
$zabbix="["+$enr+"]"

WRITE-HOST $zabbix
```

My objective is to get only the folder that exist in chosen DFS path.
For example:

On my D:\ I have the folders `fld1`, `fld2` and `fld3`
I have a DFS share for `fld1` called `Folder_DFS_Name_1` and `fld2` called `Folder_DFS_Name_2` but not `fld3`

When I run the script, it will return something like this:

```
[{"{#d:\*}":"fld1","{#$DFS}":"Folder_DFS_Name_1"},{"{#d:\*}":"fld2","{#$DFS}":"Folder_DFS_Name_2"}]
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you can solve problems like this using a comparison to $null by explicitely setting a variable to $null first, then assigning the same variable the result of the Cmdlet and finally checking if $null is still equal to your variable. If yes, the Cmdlet did not return anything. If no, the Cmdlet found an object that you can process.

In dummy-code, it looks like this:

```
$myVariable = $null
$myVariable = Get-DataFromSomeCmdlet -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($null -ne $myVariable) {
    #do somthing
}
```

In your code, it would look like this:

```
Get-ChildItem $search -Directory -Name |
ForEach-Object {
    $foldername = $_ -replace ('\\', '/')
    if (-Not ( $bypassfolder.Contains($foldername) )) {
        $existingDFSNFolder = $null
        $existingDFSNFolder = Get-DfsnFolder -Path "$DFSpath$folder*" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        if ($null -ne $existingDFSNFolder) {
            $dfsname = Get-DfsnFolder -Path "$DFScomplet$nomdossier*"
            $dfsname = $dfsname.Path
            $dfsname = $dfsname.Split('\')
            $dfsname = $dfsname[4]
            $enr = $enr + "`{`"`{`#$search`}`":`"$foldername`",`"`{`#$DFS`}`":`"$dfsname`"`},"
        }
    } }
$enr = $enr.Substring(0, $enr.Length - 1)
$zabbix = "[" + $enr + "]"
```